# How can I use a Firebase SSL Certificate with a separate DNS provider

Tags: ssl, firebase, dns, firebase-hosting, dnsimple

I have a domain I purchased and manage through http://dnsimple.com
My hosting is provided by http://firebase.google.com Firebase also provides SSL Certificates.

How do I use them together? I made the appropriate CNAME records requested by firebase on dnsimple. The domain foo.com resolves to https://foo.com but the browser complains that the record cannot be resolved. Dropping the https prefix doesn't work either.

Comment: I encourage you to wrote to DNSimple support with the domain name, as it is likely a misconfiguration, and it's really hard to provide a response here where you don't mention the real domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the A record option instead of the CNAME (recommended) option. Firebase configures the app to redirect to the root domain.